# Which numeric data type has the maximum precision?

Tags: ios, swift, math, numeric, numerical-methods

How to work with numbers like 20999998.00000000001?
Float80 is too small.

**Update**

Why does the "print" work differently?

```
print(Decimal(string: "20999998.00000000001"))// Optional(20999998.00000000001)

let a: Decimal = 20999998.00000000001
print(a)//20999998
```

What type of data should I use for a number not greater than 20,999,999.9769 with 0.00000000001 precision?

Comment: It really depends on your needs. Do you need precision or approximation?

Comment: You've completely changed your question making all of the existing answers irrelevant.

Comment: Try to find out how the compiler reads and stores numeral constants.

Comment: By curiosity, why do you need such a monstrous accuracy ? (By the way your numbers require 61 bits of mantissa, for which float80 is enough, contrary to your saying.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDecimalNumber is the most accurate one while you are working with numbers. See detailed info about Apple guide https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber